# Why specialization and template does not match?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, template-specialization

I am quite new in c++ templates.
This is the sample code I have written to test `std::enable_if_t` staff.
But it does not compile with following error:

```
No function template matches function template specialization 'print'
Candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

class IPoint
{
public:
   IPoint()
      : x(0), y(0)
   {}

   IPoint(int xValue, int yValue)
      : x(xValue), y(yValue)
   {}

public:
   int x;
   int y;
};

namespace utils
{
   template<typename T>
   typename std::enable_if_t<true, T> print(const std::string& s) 
   {
      return 0;
   }

   template<>
   inline IPoint print(const std::string& s)
   {
      return IPoint(0, 0);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you are mixing [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) with [function specialization](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/08/15/function-templates-partial-specialization-cpp/). It will not work like that. You need to pick one.

Secondly, enable if is always `true`, so it will be always selected, no matter what the `T` is.

```
std::enable_if_t<true, T>
//               ^^^^
```

You need the following (in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)) for the SFINAE to work:

```
#include <type_traits> // std::is_same

namespace utils
{
   template<typename T>
   typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<IPoint, T>::value, T>::type // T != IPoint 
      print(const std::string& s)
   {
      return 0;
   }

   template<typename T>
   typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<IPoint, T>::value, T>::type   // T == IPoint 
      print(const std::string& s)
   {
      return IPoint(0, 0);
   }
}
```

---

As a side note, in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), this will be reduced to one single template function using [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If)

```
namespace utils
{
   template<typename T>
   auto print(const std::string& s) 
   {
      if constexpr (std::is_same<IPoint, T>::value)
         return IPoint(0, 0);
      else
         return 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: @Daa, after a compiler selected a primary template, it will consider specializations. You specialize a function template for some `T`, but what is `T` in that specialization? It is not provided explicitly, and it can not be deduced.